# Dance pad not recognizing directional buttons (StepMania)

Tags: 18.04, usb

I recently installed 18.04 on a computer that was running 14.04. Before, I was running StepMania and everything worked fine. I have two dance pads that use a Dual PSX-to-USB Adaptor to connect to the PC.

Since installing 18.04, however, the pads don't work properly. All the buttons map OK, except the up, down, left and right. They aren't detected at all.

If I run antimicro, or jstest, I can see that the computer can see the buttons. However, they map them as axes instead of buttons.

When I run stepmania from CLI, it shows that it identifies the pads and identifies them as having 12 keys and 0 axes. However, it's not responding to the arrow pads.

I ran `modprobe joydev` and `modprobe analog` but this didn't fix the problem. I have heard of users having an 'axis' problem where they can't press two opposite directional buttons at the same time, but in this case, I can't press any directions at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [HIDRAW utils](https://github.com/orochimarufan/hidraw). It solved my axis issue when pressing left+right and up+down simultaneously and was able to use two dance pads at the same time. Even though your problem is different (no axis buttons work) HIDRAW utils was supposed to help make axis inputs more readable by the computer.

Since you previously used Stepmania on 14.04 I assume you probably copied over your old version of Stepmania. A clean updated copy of Stepmania might yield different results.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is a great answer, would you mind adding instructions on how to install the HIDRAW utils?